# jeditorpane caret location and string location not in sync

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I'm trying to fix a bug in this code that was made for windows but dosent work in linux( I didn't write the code), the location of the caret and the typing location is not in sync. the dot and Mark location are the same and the setMagicCaretPosition dosent work the way I think, any help?(what properties should I monitor)

this program has the same/similair issue [kernow](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kernowforsaxon/)

[bug report](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2995664&group_id=161018&atid=818177)

Comment: I see nothing untoward on Ubuntu 10.04. Can you post an http://sscce.org/ that shows the problem?

Comment: well theres a lot of code and I dont know which part is effecting the issue, essentially I'm trying to find out how the display property(where the caret blinks) and the actual edit location (where text is appended) could be "unsynced"...whats a possible scenario? I dont even know how it could happen.thanks!

Comment: @jtzero: I tried Anrew Welch's `kernow` on Mac OS and Ubuntu, but no caret anomalies appeared. BTW, I think you have to use `@` to address anyone but the author in a comment.

Comment: @trashgod: sorry still kinda new to this, thanks for your time and interest, I will attempt it on other linux computers....P.S. there is a bug reprt in kernow that seems to reference the same thing? so maybe I'm not losing my mind/making this up...? and thank you

Comment: @jtzero: Do you have a link to the `kernow` bug report?

Comment: You aren't attempting to modify Swing stuff off the AWT EDT are you? Even the bits of Swing text that are supposed to be thread-safe typically are not.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline: I'm just trying to fix this bug in an app that was made by a developer that's no longer around, it turns out kernow appears to has the same issue,to answer your question idk. also I didnt know about the thread-safe thing...
@trashgod: I added the bug report to the post here , and tried both kernow and "my" app on multiple workstations(ubuntu 10.04, fedora 12, ubuntu 9.10 --java1.6.20) all the same issue

Comment: That looks like it could be a font related issue. If you change the font used in the JEditorPane, does that change the amount the cursor is off?

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller: all the font is set as times new roman, so it wouldn't change to a default...

Comment: @jtzero: I see the same bug in `kernow` with Ubuntu 10.04. I also get an NPE in a Timer thread shortly after editing in the sandbox, which makes me wonder about `DefaultCaret`? Other panels worked normally.

Comment: @trashgod: actually I have issues with the the xslt sandbox in that app as well as the xquery one. however, I tried editing the setCaretPosition(this.getCaretPosition() + 1) and it immediately shot a "BadLocation" error as expected so its not that the caret isnt going to the end , it thinks its at the end so looking at Default caret I drudged up this "The timer thread fires asynchronously, and causes the caret to simply repaint the most recent bounding box" so the bounding box isnt at the right limit, but is updating at the right time....

Comment: for what its worth i found this "The magic caret position is set to null when the caret position changes. A timer is used to determine the new location (after the caret change). When the timer fires, if the magic caret position is still null it is reset to the current caret position"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone who comes across this and cant find an answer
try sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

there is no longer an error on either JVM
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 
OR
java version "1.6.0_18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8) (6b18-1.8-
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)